# Plot scatter plot when values are wrongly paired

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, lm, ggpmisc

I am trying to create some correlation plots based of a data frame that I created using dplyr's spread() function. When I used the spread function, it created NAs in the new data frame. This makes sense because the data frame had concentration values for different parameters at different time periods.

**Here is an example screenshot of the original data frame:**
[image]

**When I used the spread function it gave me a data frame like this(sample data):**

```
structure(list(orgid = c("11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", 
"11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", 
"11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", 
"11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD", "11NPSWRD"), 
    locid = c("11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", 
    "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2", "11NPSWRD-MORR_NPS_PR2"
    ), stdate = structure(c(9891, 9891, 9891, 9920, 9920, 9920, 
    9949, 9949, 9949, 9978, 9978, 9978, 10011, 10011, 10011, 
    10067, 10067, 10073, 10073, 10073), class = "Date"), sttime = structure(c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs"), valunit = c("uS/cm", "mg/l", 
    "mg/l", "uS/cm", "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm", "mg/l", "mg/l", 
    "uS/cm", "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm", "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm", 
    "mg/l", "uS/cm", "mg/l", "mg/l"), swqs = c("FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", 
    "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", 
    "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", 
    "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP", "FW2-TP"
    ), WMA = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), year = c(1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
    1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 
    1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L), 
    Chloride = c(NA, 35, NA, NA, 45, NA, NA, 30, NA, NA, 30, 
    NA, NA, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35, NA), `Specific conductance` = c(224, 
    NA, NA, 248, NA, NA, 204, NA, NA, 166, NA, NA, 189, NA, NA, 
    119, NA, 194, NA, NA), `Total dissolved solids` = c(NA, NA, 
    101, NA, NA, 115, NA, NA, 96, NA, NA, 79, NA, NA, 89, NA, 
    56, NA, NA, 92)), .Names = c("orgid", "locid", "stdate", 
"sttime", "valunit", "swqs", "WMA", "year", "Chloride", "Specific conductance", 
"Total dissolved solids"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem I am having is when I try and create the correlation plot it's giving me a plot with only one point.. I'm guessing this is because there are NAs in the data frame.. But when I try and filter the NAs it gives me a data frame with 0 observations.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**Example code to create correlation plot:**

```
plot1<-ggplot(data=df,aes(x="Specific conductance",y="Chloride"))+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x)+
  geom_point()
```

**I would like to create a plot like this:**
[image]

Comment: Remove quotes from `aes(x="Specific conductance",y="Chloride")`. As you have space in your column names use: `aes(x=\`Specific conductance\`,y=Chloride)`

Comment: @PoGibas when I do that I get this ->Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

Comment: And as you mentioned your data is formatted weirdly as it's only numeric values paired with NAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [remove NAs & collapse rows which have the same Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036294/collapsing-rows-where-some-are-all-na-others-are-disjoint-with-some-nas)

```r
library(tidyverse)

# clean up column names by removing spaces
df <- df %>% 
  select_all(~str_replace(., " ", "_"))

# removing NAs & collapsing rows which have the same Date 
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT2 <- unique(DT[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = stdate], by = "stdate")

library(ggpmisc)
formula1 <- y ~ x

ggplot(data = DT2, aes(x = Specific_conductance, y = Chloride)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = formula1) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")), 
               label.x.npc = "left", label.y.npc = "top",
               formula = formula1, parse = TRUE, size = 6) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thank you Tung for your answer! You rock!

Comment: btw if you want to separate the equation & R2 into different rows, use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419755/786542)

Comment: Hey Tung.. quick question.. should I be getting a warning message saying rows have been removed?

Comment: Yes, that's normal, you can ignore the warnings. If you have any doubt, double check few lines with the original data frmae

Comment: I know this is an old post... but I just realized that I don't want to collapse the dates because then I am dropping values that I want in my analysis. The stdate column has repeated dates with different values based on the sttime increasing. Is there anyway to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution is to modify data that you already have. Merge it with itself by specific columns and leave matches where both values are not `NA`.

```
# Merge data with itself
# Here I'm only guessing columns that need to match between
# Conductance and Chloride
df2 <- merge(df, df, c("orgid", "locid", "stdate"))
# This will give table with multiple duplicate rows (all possible combinations)

# Select only those combinations where both values are not NA
df2 <- subset(df2, !is.na(Chloride.x) & !is.na(`Specific conductance.y`))

# Plot
ggplot(df2, aes(`Specific conductance.y`, Chloride.x)) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "black", formula = y ~ x) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: @KWANGER Bind data by those columns so you would get numeric value paired with numeric value.